# Trying to get property of non-object in a custom delete

Tags: laravel-5

I have an query, where it returns 1 or more results. After this query, I execute a delete on these tuples.

I think it's my coding failure, but what I'm trying to do is get this select and send it by ID parameter to Delete.

```
public function TestDelet(AcademicoRequest $request)
{
    $academico = new Academico();

    $res = $request->all();

    $academico->member_id = $res->member_id;

    if($res->member_id){
        $dados_academicos[] = DB::table('academicos')->where('member_id', $res->member_id)->orderby('id')->get();

        $this-> destroy($dados_academicos->Id);
    }
}
```

List I try on postman:

```
{
  "member_id": "1",
}
```

But, return this is error: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Hope these suggestions help:

---

`$request->all();`

the all() method is returning array format, so you need to change from

> $res->member_id

into

> $res['member_id']

---

I'm assuming you are trying to delete one/many rows from database at ***academicos*** table

```
if($res['member_id']){
    Academico::where('member_id', $res['member_id'])->delete();
}
```

Comment: After you make these suggested changes, you return the error: (1/1) ErrorException
Undefined index: member_id

Answer (score 0):

Please check values of object array:

```
dd($dados_academicos)
```

If you are using laravel with mysql by default it is id not Id and with mongodb it is _id. so use

```
$this-> destroy($dados_academicos->id);
```

OR

```
$this-> destroy($dados_academicos->_id);
```

OR

```
$this-> destroy($dados_academicos['Id']);
```